# WFP driver giving 0.0.0.0 as local ip address for connection

Tags: windows, redirect, networking, driver, wfp

I am implementing a callout routine for WFP driver doing connection redirection. I have registered at the *FWPS_LAYER_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4* layer. Everything is working fine. 
When I am trying to get the local IP address for the connection, I always get it as 0. Is this expected? I am redirecting the connection to local service.

```
local_ip = RtlUlongByteSwap(inFixedValues->incomingValue
              [FWPS_FIELD_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4_IP_LOCAL_ADDRESS])
```

IN const FWPS_INCOMING_VALUES *inFixedValues received as parameter for callout routine.

The same is the case for user sid. It always comes like s-1-0-0 which is basically invalid sid

I am fetching user's sid blob as

```
inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V6_ALE_PACKAGE_ID].value.sid
```

Need help in understanding is this expected behavior or something I am missing here!

thanks

Comment: If you are programming WFP callouts, there are many cases like you. The documentation says that there is IP information, but when you get the value, there is no value, because the information is not available or determined in that context. You should give up getting information from WFP callouts and devise other methods.

Comment: Yeah, it could be the case that information is not available. MSDN should have been updated with possible uncertainty about the information availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't documented behavior as far as I know, but I've seen this callout be invoked twice for UDP connections: the first time with zero-values for the local address and port and the second time with actual values.  It's been reported [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7570194-122e-4550-8cbc-eb685f78eea0/udp-flows-with-no-port-assigned-at-fwpmlayeraleconnectredirectv4-layer?forum=wfp) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/issues/374).  I work around it by checking the address and port fields for zero-values and ignoring the callout in that case.

Comment: I am seeing the zero ip-valid port for TCP. the pointed link does talk about not getting valid IP/port, I am not sure about this and will definitely check this (Thanks for giving pointer)